# start two independent transactions with mysql

Tags: mysql, transactions, dirtyread

I want to recreate a dirty read anomaly with two independent transactions. I've started the terminal twice and connected both with my database. I've started the transaction with the command `start transaction;` in both. Then I updated one information in the first terminal window and this is what it showed me: `Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0`. After selecting all data in this table the change was there. But as I tried to show the changed data `select * from adress;` in the second terminal window, it didn't show me the change but the old data.

In the end I need to prove the dirty read anomaly and avoid this happening with the right isolation level.

Here are two screenshots of my terminal windows.

Transaction 1:

[image: transaction 1]

Transaction 2:

[image: transaction 2]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help,
Robin

Comment: Did you commit your transaction in the first terminal?

Comment: I just tried it with commit in the first terminal. The second terminal still shows the old data. Only when I commit the second terminal also the data is the same. Does it also mean that both of the transactions are over?

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit the changes on your first transaction

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

The idea of a transaction is to allow you to do a series of operations that either all must be successful, or they all mustn't happen.

Hope that helps.